# How to retrieve the value of the key changed in a child in firebase realtime database using observe

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i was trying to write a code to pull a data from the realtime database using observe for child changed. But i don't know what the mistake is but the code fails. From my debugging study, i found that the observe was successfully triggered when the value changed, but it fails when i try to get the snapshot value to a variable. How should data be retrieved in a observe for child change case.

```
func userBalance() {
DatabaseProvider.Instance.userRef.child(UserDataHandler.Instance.user_id).observe(FIRDataEventType.childChanged, with: { (snapshot) in
  print("Snapshot: ", snapshot)
  print("Snapshot Value", snapshot.value)
  guard let data = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary else {
    print("checkpoint fail test")
    return
  }
  guard let userBalance = data[Constants.BALANCE] as? String else { return }

  // update UserDefaults
  userDefault.setString(userBalance, forKey: "userBalance")

  //update local session
  UserDataHandler.Instance.balance = userBalance

})   }
```

kindly help me out, thanks in advance.

```
Debugging Data :
Snapshot:  Snap (balance) 100
Snapshot Value Optional(100)
checkpoint fail test
```

Comment: Hi, it would be of great help if someone could help me on the spot that i missed or went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks guys, i found the answer, may be it will help someone else. I am put down the new code that worked.

```
DatabaseProvider.Instance.userRef.child(UserDataHandler.Instance.user_id).observe(FIRDataEventType.childChanged, with: { (snapshot) in
  guard let key = snapshot.key as? String else { return }
  guard let value = snapshot.value as? String else { return }

  if key == Constants.BALANCE {
    guard let userBalance = value as? String else { return }

    // update UserDefaults
    userDefault.setString(userBalance, forKey: "userBalance")

    //update local session
    UserDataHandler.Instance.balance = userBalance

  }
})  }
```

The problem was that the observe detects the change in the database as one by one, so the snapshot comes as a single data for every change, if you change multiple values in a go, the observe detects it as multiple changes, one by one with each change as change of one value. So when i changed it to direct string it worked. You were right @Achref Gassoumi the problem was with the cast. Just after you told about it, i tried it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem probably is with the cast 
try the following :

```
DatabaseProvider.Instance.userRef.child(UserDataHandler.Instance.user_id).observe(FIRDataEventType.childChanged, with: { (snapshot) in

  guard let data = snapshot.value as? [<String,anyObject>] else {
    print("checkpoint fail test")
    return
  }
print (data)
```

Comment: Hi, first thanks for trying to help me out. So i tried it with AnyObject, after you said it, but i get error message 'Type AnyObject does not conform to protocol Hashable'. Its not allowing to build the project.

Comment: the error was because the key cannot be of type anyObject , I modified the answer : the key should be a string